# How to write a general proof to prove that for all $m$, $m^n \geq n^m$

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, induction

After proving $m^n \geq n^m$ for several values of $m$, it can be inferred that for every $m$ there's a $k$ such that if $n \geq k$, $m^n \geq n^m$.

In other words, this can be generalized as:

For all $m$, there's a $k$ such that for all $n$ if $n\geq k$, $m^n \geq n^m$.

The problem is, I don't know how to start.

I know $m>1$ for it to work, and this sounds inductive... however; how can I know what value of $k$ should work for a general case? Should I try induction by cases...

Assume $m$ is a natural, prove something and then conclude that $m$ has to be $m>1$? Or should I assume $m>1$ and then proceed to prove that there's a $k$ for every m such that $n \geq k$ implies  $m^n \geq n^m$.

Thanks for any advice or hints.

Answer (score 1):

Two hints:

- $m^n \ge n^m \iff m^{1/m} \ge n^{1/n}$
- the function $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ is decreasing for $x>e$

Comment: The second fact sounds really interesting, but since I haven't been introduced to it I would need to sub-prove it, which I think could be avoided... any other approaches you recommend?

Comment: You can take the derivative and get positive terms multiplying $\log x -1$, so this is achievable

Comment: @Ross Millikan I found a pattern, and after 3, every number m will meet the condition for an n >= m, so k = m will work for every case of m > 3... Can I use this information to prove the fact by induction somehow?

Comment: I don't see a nice way to do it by induction.  The step from $k$ to $k+1$ seems to assume what you are trying to prove.